# jenkins extended choice parameter plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using extended choice parameter which allows me select multiple values in single parameter.Is it possible to select or provide a checkbox to select all the options under the parameter with a single click.

```
-All
   -option1
   -option2
   -option3
```

I want the checkboxes in the above format,if i select "All"checkbox,it should select all the option and if i select option1,it should select only the option1.pls let me know is it possible with extended choice parameter plugin or there is any other plugin

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, unless you write your own front-end plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use Active choice
For more information

```
https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033180892-How-to-create-a-custom-UI-component-for-the-Active-Choices-Plugin
```